# Core data NSManagedObject subclass how to unwrap optional entity of class?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Please allow me to explain my situation, as I'm only starting with Core Data. I will try to summarise, as there is too much code.

I want to create a simple program using core data, which has:

- a Contract entity (with attributes such as number, date of signing, object of contract, fee)
- a Client entity (client name, address, idNumber)
- an Invoice entity

The Contract entity and Client entity should be in a **one-to-one** relationship. One contract has one client.

My intent is that whenever I create a contract, I also create a client (in the same Form in the same View). **I would like to, basically, pass a "contract" entity to a new view, but pull "client" attributes (name, address) from the "contract" entity**.

However, in NSManagedObject subclass, **Client is an optional class instance**.

I created an NSManagedObject subclass for each entity. Inside my Contract+CoreDataProperties swift file, I've got an @NSManaged public variable which is an optional Client.

```
extension Contract {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Contract> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Contract>(entityName: "Contract")
}

@NSManaged public var objectOfContract: String?
@NSManaged public var registrationNumber: String?
@NSManaged public var client: Client?
@NSManaged public var invoice: NSSet?
```

Now, after I fetch a contract from storage, I pass contract to a new view.

I would like to somehow pull client attributes, but from contract.client.

***How do I do it? How do I unwrap "Client?" in the NSManagedObject sub-class?***

Here's the **short version** of the code:

VIEW 1 (part of):

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var contracts: FetchedResults<Contract>

ForEach (contracts, id: \.self) {contract in
                
    NavigationLink {
       DetailContract(contract: contract)
          } label: {
            Label (...)
          }
```

So in VIEW 1 I pass contract to VIEW 2

VIEW 2 (part of):

```
struct DetailContract: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@State var contract: FetchedResults<Contract>.Element
@State var showClientDetailSheet: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            Section {
                HStack {
                    Text("Client: \(contract.wrappedClientName)")
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        showClientDetailSheet.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    }
                }  
            }
        .navigationTitle("Details")
        .sheet(isPresented: $showClientDetailSheet) {
            DetailClient(client: contract.client)
        }
    }
}
}
```

The "client" in DetailClient View is:

```
struct DetailClient: View {

@State var client: FetchedResults<Client>.Element

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            Text(client.name ?? "")
            Text(client.address ?? "")
            Text(client.idNumber ?? "")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thank you! Hope you understand, I'm new using core data, still learning!

Comment: So what is the issue here? Is client `nil`? You get any error?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting client.nil, but I figured it out in the meanwhile.

There is no need for unwrapping in the sub-class file.

When I was saving a contract entity, I wasn't calling  the "contract.client?.attribute".

I wasn't doing this:

```
                    newContract.client = Client(context: managedObjectContext)
                    newContract.client?.name = clientName
                    newContract.client?.address = clientAddress
                    newContract.client?.idNumber = clientID
                    
                    try? managedObjectContext.save()
                    dismiss()
```

Now, I changed the DetailClient view to take the attributes of client as parameters (strings), and I unwrapped the String optionals.

```
DetailClient(clientName: contract.client?.name ?? "Unknown", clientAddress: contract.client?.address ?? "Unknown", clientID: contract.client?.idNumber ?? "Unknown")
```

Thank you for your time!